# writing posts in markdown inside html-div (with zurb foundation 5 and jekyll)

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

i am trying to create a blog with jekyll and zurb foundation 5.
therefore id like to use some of the html structure of the foundation framework inside the posts, the post content indeed is written in markdown.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 columns">

     ### Header of List

    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3

  </div>
  <div class="small-9 columns">...</div> 
</div>
```

The markdown list works right but not the divs. 
the closing tags of the divs get translated raw als plane text to "".

**how can i use markdown properly inside a div structure?**

thanks for your help!

Comment: You syntax is correct and Jekyll is rendering exactly this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markdown gets disabled when using `<div>`-containers. To turn it on inside a `<div>` you have to simply put **`markdown="1"`** inside the `<div>` like so:

```
<div class="row" markdown="1">
  <div class="small-3 columns" markdown="1">

     ### Header of List

    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3

  </div>
  <div class="small-9 columns">...</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks!
I tried to this before but only on the first div "row", didnt know that you had to put it into every cascade.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you have to put it at least into the last one (the one with markdown markup in it). Try it out. I just did it to be sure, the parser would not skip a `<div>`.

Comment: Yes you're right, it seeems that it has to be the **innermost** div that contains markdown="1".